# What difference can the windows-user-settings make, when running a selenium-script?

Tags: python, windows, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wrote some testing scripts with selenium, and they were working fine as long as I started them from my account, on a Windows 7 machine. But when a colleague started it from his account, on the same machine, some of the tests had a NoSuchElementException. What can cause that difference, maybe something the graphic-settings like the display resolution?
The scripts are written in Python, they are using Selenium-Webdriver with Firefox. The PC has Windows 7 Enterprise, 64 Bit, Service Pack 1, with Python 2.7.12 installed.

Comment: A `NoSuchElementException` should not really be dependent on much other than the element either existing or not existing. Have you tried running the tests multiple times on your own account? Perhaps there are some elements that take some more time than expected to be created.

Comment: Yes, we tried it several times on both accounts. It’s always the same error at the same place, when it tries to find a table by ID.
I thought, maybe it’s in the graphic settings because they make the element take longer to be visible, or something like that. But of cause it may also be something with the network settings causing a latency, or something completely different.  
All in all it has be a difference between our both accounts, as it constantly works on my account and it doesn’t on his.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I’ve found the explanation: It’s the screen resolution. My colleague and I were connecting to the PC using RDP, and his connection had a smaller screen resolution than mine.

When I was starting a connection, explicitly setting the resolution to his values, the tests produced errors, and when I then started a new connection with my original settings, the tests were running fine again. And this was reproducible.

I think the background is that on the page are many elements, which are moving dynamically with the page size, and some elements, which are fix or have a minimum size. So it’s possible that an element is covered by another, if the screen is too small, and with it the browser-window. Also a fix element could be partly out of the viewport.